# Convolution of two equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the convolution of $f(t) = t$ and $g(t) = e^{t}$

$$(f*g)(t)= ?$$

If I am correct, I am able to find the Laplace Transform of each individually, then multiply them together.

Let $L(x)$ equal the Laplace Transform of $x$

$L(t)*L(e^t)= (1/s^2)*1/(s-1)$ but I am not getting the correct answer.

Help please!

Comment: Is $\mathcal{L}(f)*\mathcal{L}(g)=\mathcal{L}(f*g)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A direct computation shows that $$f*g=e^t*t=\int_0^t{e^x(t-x) dx}=t(e^t-1)-(te^t-e^t+1)=e^t-t-1$$ And $$L(e^t-t-1)=\frac{1}{s-1}-{1\over s^2}-{1\over s}=\frac{s^2-(s-1)-s(s-1)}{s^2(s-1)}=\frac{1}{s^2(s-1)}$$ as desired.